# Nitrousのファイルのダウンロード

Tags: ruby-on-rails

毎々お世話になっております。新米エンジニアです。

Nitrous でrailsのWEBアプリケーションを開発しております。
ネット上にあるソースを開発もしくはフォルダー毎にダウンロードする方法はございますか？
現在、ファイル上で右クリックでのダウンロード方法は把握しているのですが、フォルダー毎でのダウンロード方法をご存知の方、ご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

今のところ Nitrous の Web IDE では一括ダウンロードできないようです。

当方で確認したところ、[Nitrous デスクトップ](https://www.nitrous.io/desktop) から Nitrous Desktop をダウンロードし、起動します。
あとは接続して、下記のスクリーンショットのように File Sync を有効にします。
※これは Windows での解説です。Mac も若干違いはあれど同様だと思われます。

[image: Nitrous Desctop - File sync]

すると `C:\{ユーザ名}\Nitrous\{マシン名}` にプロジェクトファイルが全て同期されています。
これでダウンロードできますので、お試しください。